# PHP: How to pass parameters to a dependency container

Tags: php

I'm making a simple class for dependencies so as not to create multiple instances:

```
class Container {

    private static $instance = array();

    public function use($class) {

        if (!isset(self::$instance[$class])) {

            self::$instance[$class] = new $class();

        }

        return self::$instance[$class];

    }

}
```

And now I can use it like:

```
$Container = new Container;

$Class = $Container->use('SomeClass');
```

This would be the equivalent of:

```
$Class = new Class;
```

However, how would I modify this `Container` class so that I can pass (an unknown number of) parameters to the classes I am requesting an instance of? Like if I had to do this:

```
$Class = new Class($param1, $param2);
```

Comment: why not add a `__construct()` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie What purpose would that serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I mean by adding a `__construct()`. The construct would run as you instantiate the class, taking your multiple desired arguments in an array format.

```
class Container
{
    private static $instance = [];

    public function useClass($class, $args)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance[$class])) {
            self::$instance[$class] = new $class($args);
        }
        return self::$instance[$class];
    }
}

class User
{
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function __construct($args)
    {
        $this->name = $args['name'];
        $this->age = $args['age'];
    }

}


$Container = new Container;

$args = [
    "name" => 'John',
    "age" => 29
];

$user = $Container->useClass('User', $args);

var_dump($Container);
var_dump($user);
```

Comment: I loaded up just three small classes and I'm getting Fatal error: allowed memory bytes exhausted...

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this as a test for yourself? If that's not the case and you're not aware, there's multiple libraries in PHP that allow you to do exactly what you're asking for: a dependency injection container.

As a simple one, you can have a look at Pimple for PHP. A very simple container.

If you want to carry on with your solution, you should use something like the `func_get_args();` function.

Comment: I'm looking at Pimple, but even that is more than I need. I don't see why a simple class such as this wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Pimple is really just an array containing objects, nothing else... So it's actually the same as your class, don't think of it as a full blown dependency injection container.